# QField doesn't load .TIF and .png files

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qfield

I'm using QField v. 2.1.4 Bumblebee on two smartphones and I'm trying to work on a project with a .png and a .TIF files that I extracted from two WMS maps. I tried the maps on two smartphones:
-The .png works just for one of the smartphones
-The .TIF doesn't work for both the devices.

I get the error:

> The following layers can't be loaded (satellite.png, soil.tif), please
> check the files and modify your QGIS project.

The project was made with QGIS v. 3.24 Tisler and the images work fine.

Comment: I daily do the same since I need to update some information in the project through QGis. Nothing seems to change. I also tried to uninstall Qfield without any result. Thanks

Comment: Is one of the smartphone on iOS?

Comment: No, they are both on Android. Thanks